# Best practice to avoid N+1 when listing objects retrieved by a method in an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to figure the best way to fix a N+1 problem in my rails app.

Let's say I have a model `Student`, which has a `many` association of `terms`.

```
student = Student.find_by_name('John')
student.terms 
# [{term: 1}, {term: 2}, {term: 3}]
```

So, I need to be able to show the list of student terms but also need to show the previous term in the same view. Currently, for this I have a method that gets the previous term by the attribute `start_at` which is a DateTime value equivalent to the first  day of the term.

```
# Term.rb
def previous_term
  Term.where("start_at < ?", start_at).order(start_at: :desc).first&.start_at
end
```

But using this method in the terms list makes a query for each term for each Student

```
- @terms.each do |term|
  %td= term.start_at # list current term start_at
  %td= term.previous_term # show previous term start_at - N+1 is here
```

I've thought about loading all student terms in the controller and creating a class method in model Term, this method would detect the previous Term from a ordered collection of Terms.

```
# Term.rb
def self.get_previous(term_collection, term_id)
  term_collection.detect do |term|
    # logic to filter and get the previous term
  end
end
```

This way it would be filtering the objects in memory instead of making database connections, buuuuut I know there is a better and smarter way to do it (maybe best practice?).

Comment: Also you should post the queries which ruby on rails is generating.. Also you should post the CREATE TABLE structures as this is a performance question we need to know datatypes and indexes.. Also a `EXPLAIN` would also help.

Comment: `term.previous_term` if that should look into the last other record look of SQL's `LAG()` window function.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, I'll take the performance tag out. I'm really not looking to  assess the database performance for each existent solution, but just to know a practical way to avoid the N+1

Comment: removing N+1 problem is still optimisation so it remeans a performance question.. also we need that information that i asked annyway.. Otherwise the question is unclear and will most likely will not get answers or will get voteclosed see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines

Comment: Also also ORM's or using some functions are known for making N+1 problems one way is to make a VIEW in PostgreSQL and query the VIEW instead from ruby..

Comment: I would suggest, you can load all the data in `@terms` itself so that you don't need to  execute a query for every student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your ordered terms `student.terms.order(start_at: :desc)`, you can create a ruby array `loop with index` in your view

```
- @terms.each_with_index do |term, index|
  %td= term.start_at
  - if index > 0
    %td= @terms[0..index-1].pluck(:name)
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for the answer! this may be part of the solution. Your answer would apply if we are listing the @terms of only 1 student, but what about the terms of many students. I've noted that "student.terms" can be eager loaded and then create a helper method or even a model method with your logic to get the previous one.

Comment: Yah. It's great that u find it useful. You're right, you can use `Student.includes(:terms)` and then apply this solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of `previous_term` to

```
def previous_term
  where("start_at < ?", start_at).order(start_at: :desc).first&.start_at
end
```

So you'd be able to call

```
student.terms.previous_term
```

---

Alternative with in Ruby, since you already have the collection of `terms = student.terms`, use [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) (or `min_by`). Something like:

```
previous_term = terms.max_by { |term| term.start_at } # or terms.max_by(&:start_at)
```

Comment: Thanks, but he "previous_term" method would still create a query for each student term, which is what I would like to avoid.